# How to fix MS Access EnumFields error in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I just started studying VBA for Access. I am therefore using some examples of site "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/access-home".

When the code contains "EnumFiels" its execution generates the error "Sub or Function not defined".

I can't understand the reason for it and, above all, I don't know how to eliminate it.

For instance:

```
Sub WhereX() 

    Dim dbs As Database, rst As Recordset 
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb") 
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT LastName, " _ 
        & "FirstName FROM Employees " _ 
        & "WHERE LastName = 'King';")        
    rst.MoveLast 

    EnumFields rst, 12 

    dbs.Close 
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/from-clause-microsoft-access-sql search for sub enumfields here

Comment: "Sub EnumFields(rst As Recordset, intFldLen As Integer) " and so on,
you need to copy all that code to your module and it should work

Comment: it looks like not some built-in function. I don't know why MS listed its definition in one place and then use it without reference in other places

Comment: @sarh " It calls the EnumFields procedure, which prints the contents of a Recordset object to the Debug window."  I can't activate the Debug window. I can't find it in the Debug Menu and Window Menu.

Comment: menu View -> Immediate window, Immediate panel should appear in the bottom, it shows Debug output

Comment: @sarh Done. But when I run the code (without the Sub you suggested) nothing appears in the Debug window and I am reported the usual "Function not defined" error. Regarding your Sub, I would not know how to define the body of the procedure, that is, how to get a query or a table with the result of the EnumFields.

Comment: "you need to copy all that code to your module". I am sorry I don't know how to explain it in different way.

Comment: Need to copy/paste the EnumFields procedure into a general module.

Comment: sarh wrote: "Sub EnumFields(rst As Recordset, intFldLen As Integer)  AND SO ON". 
What does it mean ? I only see the declaration of a function with two parameters, which should be used in the main procedure instead of "EnumField rst, 12". But what should be the body of this function? Where should I declare it?
sar wrote: "you need to copy all that code to your module". 
But what code are we talking about? Should I copy the body of the Sub WhereX into the body of the "Sub EnumFields(rst As Recordset, intFldLen As Integer) "? And what arguments should I pass to that function?

Comment: June7 wrote: "Need to copy/paste the EnumFields procedure into a general module." Are you referring to sarah's procedure, which I haven't figured out yet how to define? Or some definition of EnumFields found somewhere? Finally, I looked for the definition of "General Module", but found nothing about it. What is it and where is it located?